# how to import subnet when it is declared in a vpc module with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, terraform, subnet

I have used terraform module to create a VPC

```
module "vpc_XYZ" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.14.4"
  name = "xxx"
  cidr = "yyy"
  azs              = [....]
  public_subnets   = ["CIDR","CIDR"] 
}
```

The vpc and its subnets exists. I want to import them.
The import of the vpc itself works fine

```
terraform import module.vpc_XYZ.aws_vpc.this[0]  vpc-0e70*****
```

however, when trying to import a subnet, I am not succeeding. I don't know if it is a syntax problem or simply it is impossible (since no explicit resource is declared for subnets)

```
    terraform import 'module.vpc_XYZ.aws_subnet.public[0]' subnet-*******
Error: Import to non-existent module
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ARNs and IDs of subnets using the following module properties:

```
module.vpc_XYZ.private_subnet_arns #. List of ARNs of private subnets
module.vpc_XYZ.private_subnets     #. List of IDs of private subnets
module.vpc_XYZ.public_subnet_arns #. List of ARNs of public subnets
module.vpc_XYZ.public_subnets     #. List of IDs of public subnets
```